# method call when using Android Support Library

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am using Android Support library v4 and v7, through the [Android Developer page](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) I have set up the libraries.

However I am confused with the method calls,for example, the method:

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

works only at API level 11+, but there is a compatible version as:

```
ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(this);
```

So I wonder if I have to add both codes like this:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else
            ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(this);
```

Is this necessary or I only need the compatible version?

---

It seems that use the compatible version is enough.

However I often found this kinds of code:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
}
```

Then I wonder what's the purpose of this condition judgment?

Answer (score 4):

if you are using `ActionBarActivity` or `Sherlock` activities use

```
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()
```

Answer (score 3):

The compabitible version would work fine for both. So, use

```
ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use

```
        ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(this);
```

As you are including the suport library so you can only use this.

Comment: @hguser it seems in your given example there is no method from support library. .. for different version you may want different behavior.